# Is there a way to select everything in an array in scala?

Tags: arrays, scala

I have this array:

```
val lines: Array[LineSprite] = new Array[LineSprite](26)
```

And I want to be able to select everything in it at once.  How do I go about doing this?

I know selecting one element in the array would look like this:
    lines(0)

But how do I select all at once?

---

That array has 26 elements.  I need to change the color of each element.  To do that for one element I would do it like this:

```
lines(0).setColor(Color.blue)
```

Instead of having one of those pieces of code for each element, how can I do it all at once?

Thanks

Comment: it is not clear what is *select* for all elements (how it is different from having original array), can you add desired result?

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess by 'select' you mean apply the same operation to all. In that case, you should use the `foreach` method available on all `Traversable`s, like :

```
lines.foreach( _.setColor(Color.blue))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is usually done with either `foreach` method (if you're performing some side effects, like setting color, printing or something else) or `map` method (if you care about result):

```
lines.foreach(l => l.setColor(Color.blue))
val squares = List(1,2,3,4).map(n => n * n) 
// squares are now List(1,4,9,16)
// note that line below is wrong
val squares = List(1,2,3,4).foreach(n => n * n) 
// squares now is Unit (aka void) because foreach doesn't return anything
```

Those methods defined for literally every build-in collection and arrays.